# What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

Tags: java

This is my code

```
class Euler5
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
 long i=2520l;
 int flag= 1;
 if(flag == 1)
 {
  search:
  for(int j=10;j<=20;j++)
   {
    long a=i%j;
    if(a!=0)
    {
     i+=20;
     break search ;
    }
    if(j==20)
    {
    flag=0;
    }
   }
 }
 System.out.print(i);

   }
 }
```

It always print 2540. I found other way to solve it. But what is hitting me is why is this not working??

Comment: Define: _"Not Working"_

Comment: What do you mean? Do you get an exception? Do you get wrong result? Which should be the correct result?

Comment: the aim of the program is to find the smallest no which is divisible by all no from 1 to 20 . and 2540 is not that no(Checked).So what i figure out is the if block is running only once

Answer (score 3):

Replace `if(flag == 1)` with `while (flag == 1)`. Otherwise you will only ever going to iterate once over the 11 values.

Comment: I already did in my answer : `Otherwise you will only ever going to iterate once over the 11 values.` Try to debug your code or try to iterate over it by hand and you will understand what I mean.

Comment: @user2644549 **An if statement is not a loop**

Answer (score 1):

It is because:

1. after first iteration, you are increasing `j` by `1`.
2. on the second iteration `i % j` is `!= 0`.
3. in if condition, you are incrementing `i` by `20` causing `i = 2540`.
4. you are breaking the loop there.
5. and hence the result is `2540`.

Comment: but then also it should go back to the if loop and then increment the value and check again

Comment: @user2644549: No. `break` breaks the `for` loop. `if` is not a *loop statement* .

Answer (score 1):

It because when your for loop execute second time value of `j` will be `11` which leads to your expression to
`long a=2520/11`
which set value of `a to 1` which not satisfied your if condition and it enter your if condition

```
if(a!=0)
{
   i+=20;
   break search ;
}
```

after that it will break your for loop and terminate your execution which give output 2540 always.

Answer (score 1):

your approach doesn't seems to be the right one. Your for have to be from 1 to 20 not 10 to 20. And you should run all this in a while loop as Ivaylo Strandjev said. Maybe a simpler solution is to divide 2 to 20 numbers into prime factor and add unique factors

e.g. :

```
2 => 1 * 2
3 => 1 * 3
4 => 1 * 2 * 2
5 => 1 * 5
6 => 1 * 2 * 3
```

Then you keep unique one

```
1 * 2 => keep both
1 * 3 => keep only 3
1 * 2 * 2 => keep only the second 2
1 * 5 => keep only 5
1 * 2 * 3 => keep nothing

total 1 * 2 * 3 * 2 * 5 = 60 is the smallest int divisible by 2,3,4,5 and 6
```

You'll find 17,907,120 as your solution

I'm not good at Java :(